How to host react app with a custom root url?
The root url of my React application is /movies, not /. And there are detail pages like: /movies/:id. I want to host my app. But no matter what I try, it starts with / root url. And I'm presented with a blank page. I also get 404 when I type /movies in the url.

I tried hosting with netlify, but it didn't work. (I just dragged the build file)
I tried hosting with github pages using the gh-pages package, but the result was the same.

This is my index.tsx. How can i solve this?
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  [
    {
      path: '/',
      children: [
        {
          path: '/movies',
          element: <MoviesList />,
        },
        {
          path: '/movies/:id',
          element: <MovieDetail />,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  { basename: '/movies' }
);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>


I used environment variables for this purpose. React Router is missing many features you'd think were no-brainers, I'm afraid.

Have you tried /movies/movies?

Yes, i have tried /movies/movies, but still redirects 404 page.

Have you tried /movies ?

Yes, I  have tried that too. Still 404 page

Are you hosting/serving your app from a "/movies" directory on the server? If not, then there's no need for the "/movies" basename property. If you are serving from "/movies" then you likely don't want to also render any "/movies" routes because then you'll have URL paths that look like "/movies/movies/*". Does this make sense? Where and how are you building and deploying/serving your app? Please [edit] to clarify and include a complete [mcve].

you can try this way
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  [
        {
          path: '/movies',
          element: <MoviesList />,
        },
        {
          path: '/movies/:id',
          element: <MovieDetail />,
        }
  ]
);


This time it was hosted at the / url again, when I tried the / url showed a blank page. This time the / url was redirected directly to 404.

You can create one home component , at / you can point this home component. In side home component, provide links for the movie list and movie details.

@Enes do you want the app to go /movies when we hit  /

Yes, exactly :) Simply, when we type react-app.com and click enter. I'm waiting for react-app.com/movies to open. The /movies url should act as the root url.

Before that make sure /movies works fine @Enes

I'm also faced the blank page problem when i want custom URL to be base. Then resolved by using simple Navigate component and removed the children in root / like this.
import { Navigate, createBrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

const router = createBrowserRouter(
    [
      {
        path: '/',
        Component : ()=> <Navigate to={'/'}/>
      },
      {
        path: 'movies',
        element: <MoviesList />,
        children: [
            {
              path: 'movies/:id',
              element: <MovieDetail />,
            }
        ]
      }
    ]
);

